# C++ How to validate user input real number in a separate function?

Tags: c++, function, validation

For an assignment I must replace all repeated blocks with functions, but I'm having trouble understanding how to do this with my validation loop. 
I'm currently using while loops within the code to check that the number entered is between 0 and 500. I would like to set up a function to replace these lines of code (or most of them):

```
while (inMoney < 0 || inMoney > 500)
        {
            cout << "ERROR: invalid conversion value of '" << inMoney
                << "'. " << endl;
            cout << "Enter a value to convert between 0 and 500: ";
            cin >> inMoney;
        }
```

I currently have this for my function:

```
double validate()
{
    double inMoney;
    cout << "Enter a value to convert between 0 and 500: ";
    cin >> inMoney;
    while (inMoney < 0 || inMoney > 500)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: invalid conversion value of '" << inMoney
            << "'. " << endl;
        cout << "Enter a value to convert between 0 and 500: ";
        cin >> inMoney;
    }
    return(inMoney);
}
```

and I'm trying to call it within int main() by doing this:

```
switch (code)
    {
    case 'a':
        cout << "\nUS Dollar -> British Pound" << endl;
        validate();
        outMoney = inMoney * USDtoPND;
        cout << "$" << inMoney << " equals "
            << (char)PND_SYMBOL << outMoney << endl;
        break;
```

I feel like I'm missing something about the way the function is called and/or how to actually structure this sort of validation. Do I need to leave the cin statement outside of my validate function? Does the validate function need to come after the main function? It currently compiles but when I enter a and it runs validate() I come up with a run time error that says that inMoney is not properly initialized.

Comment: You shouldn't represent money values as `double` or `float`, the bookkeepers will be thankful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is 99% fine, I would only:

- Change it's name to `readDouble()`, since this is what it actually does
- Fix the `return` statement, since it's not a function call, to `return inMoney;`

Then, instead of:

```
cout << "\nUS Dollar -> British Pound" << endl;
validate();
outMoney = inMoney * USDtoPND;
```

Which is incorrect because you don't save the return value into `inMoney`, simply use:

```
cout << "\nUS Dollar -> British Pound" << endl;
inMoney = readDouble();
outMoney = inMoney * USDtoPND;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're validate function is fine, the only thing is that the value that its returning is not actually set to a variable in your main switch code.  So change the line you're calling validate() function as such (assuming the inMoney is also of type double):

```
switch (code)
    {
    case 'a':
        cout << "\nUS Dollar -> British Pound" << endl;
        inMoney = validate();  // change here
        outMoney = inMoney * USDtoPND;
        cout << "$" << inMoney << " equals "
            << (char)PND_SYMBOL << outMoney << endl;
        break;
```